# how to inject html page in ng-view

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-view

All the codes I found on any of tutorial was to inject a message string rather than html page.
how do I inject html page using ng-view? Say structure of SPA is 2 links "Add" and "View"
Add injects add.html and View injects View.html

Comment: I would sure like to see those tutorials because any docs on routers (ngroute or ui-router) show how to use templates and templateUrl's. You have been mislead

Comment: This is the official example of `ng-view` and `ng-route` : http://plnkr.co/edit/c4daKMuLef6lgjnSyWIE?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Using

> ng-bind-html

Your HTML code will look like

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</div>
```

You can bin html in following ways

```
angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.myHTML =
     'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
     '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
}]);
```

It's recommended to bind html rather then htmlpage.

Comment: Can you be more ellaborative with example? I found this example on angularjs website. Like I want to bind my html page so in controller instead of giving 'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
     '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>'; I want to put source of html file

Comment: "It's recommended to bind html rather then htmlpage" I would like to see what is your source for that.